# OpenSSH config in PuTTY or equivalent Windows tool

Tags: windows, putty, openssh

Is there a way to import an OpenSSH configuration file in PuTTY or any other equivalent tool that runs on Windows?

Context:
We have a project with a pretty large amount of servers (>100). We use an auto generated OpenSSH configuration file in order to connect to the different servers (We use either Mac or Linux bash).
However colleagues from another company are forced to use Windows and are not allowed to install WLS, Cygwin or similar. It would be very impractical if we had to type in all SSH connections in their PuTTY clients.

Thanks and best regards,

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [Microsoft build of OpenSSH for Windows](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH).

It includes these client tools:

- `scp.exe`
- `sftp.exe`
- `ssh.exe`
- `ssh-add.exe`
- `ssh-keygen.exe`
- `ssh-keyscan.exe`

On Windows 10 version 1803 or newer and Windows 11, you already have OpenSSH built-in. On older versions of Windows 10, it can be installed as an optional Windows feature. On yet older versions of Windows, you can just extract the client-side tools from a .zip ([latest release](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases)), no installation is need.

---

Similarly, [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) also comes with its Windows build of OpenSSH client tools. Again, no installation needed.

The same set of tools is included. Also in a form of `.exe` files.

---

*PuTTY cannot use OpenSSH configuration files.*